# Match data in two files

Tags: python, readlines

I'm trying to match (what are network logon usernames) in two files. The All is a text file of names I'm (or will be) interested to match. Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
def find_files(directory, pattern):
    #directory= (raw_input("Enter a directory to search for Userlists: ")
    directory=("c:\\TEST")
    os.chdir(directory)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
                filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
                yield filename


for filename in find_files('a-zA-Z0-9', '*.txt'):
    with open (filename, "r") as file1:
       with open ("c:/All.txt", "r") as file2:
            list1 = file1.readlines()[18:]
            list2 = file2.readlines()
            for i in list1:
                for j in list2:
                    if i == j:
```

I'n new to python and am wondering if this is the best, and most efficient way of doing this. It seems, to me even as a newbie a little clunky, but with my current coding knowledge is the best I can come up with at the moment.
Any help and advice would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to read *one* file into memory first, storing it in a set. Membership testing in a set is very efficient, **much** more so than looping over the lines of the second file for every line in the first file.

Then you only need to read the second file, and line by line process it and test if lines match.

What file you keep in memory depends on the size of `All.txt`. If it is < 1000 lines or so, just keep that in memory and compare it to the other files. If `All.txt` is really large, re-open it for every `file1` you process, and read only the first 18 lines of `file1` into memory and match those against every line in `All.txt`, line by line.

To read just 18 lines of a file, use `itertools.islice()`; files are iterables and `islice()` is the easiest way to pick a subset of lines to read.

Reading `All.txt` into memory first:

```
from itertools import islice

with open ("c:/All.txt", "r") as all:
    # storing lines without whitespace to make matching a little more robust
    all_lines = set(line.strip() for line in all)

for filename in find_files('a-zA-Z0-9', '*.txt'):
    with open(filename, "r") as file1:
        for line in islice(file1, 18):
            if line.strip() in all_lines:
                 # matched line
```

If `All.txt` is large, store those 18 lines of each file in a set first, then re-open `All.txt` and process it line by line:

```
for filename in find_files('a-zA-Z0-9', '*.txt'):
    with open(filename, "r") as file1:
        file1_lines = set(line.strip() for line in islice(file1, 18))
    with open ("c:/All.txt", "r") as all:
        for line in all:
            if line.strip() in file1_lines:
                 # matched line
```

Note that you do *not* have to change directories in `find_files()`; `os.walk()` is already passed the directory name. The `fnmatch` module also has a `.filter()` method, use that to loop over `files` instead of using `fnmatch.fnmatch()` on each file individually:

```
def find_files(directory, pattern):
    directory = "c:\\TEST"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
            yield os.path.join(root, basename)
```